# Array to Map through for loop

Tags: java

I know its a very trivial issue, but I still need some help.
I have an array and I want to get its element into a map.

```
 public static Map<String, String> getSomeId() {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    File folder = new File("src/main/resources/someData");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            map.put("someId", listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(0, 13));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

I know that the content of the map gets overwritten in every loop and my map will contains only the last element put into.
How can I get all element of the array into my map?

Thank you!

Comment: Each key (here `"someId"`) must be unique. Putting a new value under the same key overwrites the previous value.

Comment: If you're using the same key for all elements a map would be the wrong structure. Either use a list or a unique key per element.

Comment: What is the plan? How do you want to get back those elements? You might need a `Set`.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Thomas is right. In this case you need to change structure from Map to List, because the reason to use Map is to have unique keys and their values to that keys

Answer (score 3):

what about this?

```
map.put("someId" + i, listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(0, 13));
```